# suggestion for Automation testing tool for flutter based crossplatform app

Tags: automated-testing, mobile-applications

We are looking to automate our mobile app(Android) which is developed using flutter.
Any suggestions on tools.
We tried testproject but the tool is not able to identify all the elements. Its not consistent in identifying the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what context your app is using (Flutter, NATIVE, or WEBVIEW).
There is "Flutter Driver" but you must be able to script tests using Dart.

If I was asked to write automated tests for a new mobile app created with Flutter, I would look into using "Appium Flutter Driver" which supports multiple languages.

https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver